Optimizing Deploy Time for Large Laravel/Vue Monolith - Offload Build to Separate Server?
I’m working on a large monolithic project using Laravel and Vue, and I'm running into a major issue with CPU usage during deployments. Currently, whenever I run npm run prod, the CPU on my server hits 100%, and the build process takes around 15 minutes to complete, severely affecting performance.
My current setup involves an EC2 instance on AWS, and I’m wondering if there’s a way to offload the build process to a completely separate server instead of running it on my production server. My idea is to run the build on a different server and then simply copy the built files over to production.
Has anyone tried this approach, or is there a recommended way to handle such scenarios? I’m open to suggestions on best practices for optimizing the deployment process for large Laravel/Vue projects.
Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated!
Thanks in advance!
